# how to access the MembershipProvider.GetPassword method

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-membership

I have implemented Membership Provider in my ASP.NET MVC app. Membership provider has the method `MembershipProvider.GetPassword` which I have overridden and implemented.

The question would be how to access this method from code? I have tried like this `Membership.GetPassword` but compiler gives error that such method do not exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `GetPassword` method wasn't exposed in the [Membership](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membership.aspx) static class. So you could simply use the [Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membership.provider.aspx) property to get the current provider and call any method you like on it:

```
var pwd = Membership.Provider.GetPassword("username", "answer");
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this answer on the ASP.NET forum helps

http://forums.asp.net/t/1287776.aspx/1

It points you to that...
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipprovider.getpassword.aspx

The docs say the following:

> > Takes, as input, a user name and a password answer and retrieves the password for that user from the data source and returns the password
> >     as a string.
>
> The GetPassword method ensures that the EnablePasswordRetrieval flag
>   is set to true before performing any action. If
>   EnablePasswordRetrieval is false, a NotSupportedException exception is
>   thrown.
>
> GetPassword also checks the value of the RequiresQuestionAndAnswer
>   property. If RequiresQuestionAndAnswer is true, GetPassword checks the
>   value of the supplied answer parameter against the stored password
>   answer in the data source. If they do not match, a
>   MembershipPasswordException exception is thrown.
>
> If your custom membership provider supports hashed passwords, the
>   GetPassword method should throw an exception if the
>   EnablePasswordRetrieval property is set to true and the password
>   format is set to Hashed. Hashed passwords cannot be retrieved.

HTH